# Let me click on the Collective's Article title please

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, collectives, articles

I can click the post title for questions but not article titles?

My most common use-case is to send a question into a new tab with Ctrl+click and interact with the original page to go elsewhere.

A close second is to refresh the page to check for edits.

Just a quality-of-life thing I guess.

[image: Image with an arrow pointing to the title of an (arbitrary) article, with an attached meme saying "let me click! Let me cliiiick!!"]

[For your clicking displeasure](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud/articles/68104924/listen-for-authentication-state-in-android)

Comment: I was going to post this request a few hours ago but thought it wouldn't get much support because not many people use it. Glad to find out I was wrong. I use it (in both use cases you mentioned) very frequently. That said, `Ctrl+click` is inexcusable if you're using a mouse. Seriously, the middle click is so underrated!

Comment: @41686d6564 I prefer the middle-click as well but during my IT support experience I find that most users avoid it because they butcher the action. They have a hard enough time left-clicking their mouse without introducing unnecessary movement and highlighting the text or enabling scroll with middle click. Ctrl+click just has a higher success rate in my experience. Middle click could also be unknowingly assigned to perform some other action so I don't rely on that standard. Don't forget that most laptop trackpads forgo a dedicated middle click. I appreciate your outrage though =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for the feedback. This request has been implemented; titles of Articles are now clickable.